# Azure Function not reporting failure to Event Grid

Tags: azure-eventgrid

@azuresupport #azTechHelp I have an event grid topic with an Azure Function subscriber that has a CosmosDB output binding. Here is the function

```
export default async (context, eventGridEvent) => {

    try {

        context.log(`Saving Asset`);
        context.log(`subject : ${eventGridEvent.subject}`)
        context.log(`eventType : ${eventGridEvent.eventType}`)

        var importObject = eventGridEvent.data;

        if(!importObject.asset.id)
        {
            throw new Error("Supplied Asset does not have an ID specified, aborting!");
        }
        else
        {
            context.log(`Successfully exported asset(${eventGridEvent.data.objectId}) to Cosmos`);
            context.bindings.outputDocument = importObject.asset;
        }

    }
    catch (err) {
        context.log.error(err);
        context.log.error(`Error Processing Event Grid Object : ${eventGridEvent}`);
        throw(err);
    }
};
```

The logic in this function will (generally) never fail, however the Cosmos DB binding can fail (and is failing due to a throughput limit). So the function fails, but thats ok our Event Grid will retry, right? Wrong!

[Image : Azure Function Failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciHaK.png)

The problem is that the Event Grid doesn't register the failure and in turn **never** retries the event.

[Image : EG Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCmec.png)

Now we can code the function to do the Cosmos CRUD inside the function and force the error, or maybe create our own binding but we would like to stick with the built in Cosmos binding.

Can someone in Azure take a look pls?

Comment: Do you need to add a context.done in the above code?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#contextdone-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because once event **reached** Azure function, it was considered a delivered success and the outcome of the function execution didn't not contribute to the http response

It was a known [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/issues/35) and fixed in lastest [eventgrid extension release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta5), I would say you should get in a week or two, if not, please open an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/issues)

Comment: Thanks watashiSHUN, I'll check in on this in a couple of weeks and see if the issue is resolved.